# Why does h1 header look wider in Firefox than in other browsers

Tags: html, css

I am puzzled by this situation. Here the jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/jkxy24x5/

Here is HTML:

```
<h1>Test Header</h1>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

h1 {
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

h1 {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

h1 {
    color: #999999;
    font-family: "Arial Narrow",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.3em;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 12px;
}
```

In the above, I extracted exact CSS code and their order from the actual website. The h1 text looks wider in Firefox than in other browsers. How can I make it look narrower in Firefox, just like in other browsers?

Comment: Looks the same to me.

Comment: Because chrome does have Arial Narrow font and Firefox does not, try removing Arial Narrow font family and it should be same

Comment: @insanebits - As I asked Grapser below, aren't fonts based on the system, not the browser (not counting web fonts)?

Comment: @curious1 I guess different browsers might have integrated set of fonts, in this case Chrome had this font and Firefox did not. That's why you should use webfonts

Comment: @insanebits - But Arial Narrow is a Microsoft font, not made by Google and not part of the default Chrome package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because

```
font-family: "Arial Narrow",
```

is not recognized by Firefox.

but you can fix it if you Try to add font-stretch: condensed

http://jsfiddle.net/jkxy24x5/1/

Comment: If "Arial Narrow", what is the font used by FF? Can I control which font to use in FF in this case? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to add font-stretch: condensed

Comment: I'm no font expert, but aren't fonts based on the system, not the browser (not counting web fonts)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks a lot narrower in FF now, very similar to what I see in other browsers. Thanks!!!

Comment: @j08691, it goes both ways

Comment: Grasper, I assume the added font-stretch: condensed has no effect on the display in Chrome and other browsers, and it just narrows how it is displayed in FF, correct ?

Comment: @curious1, yes, it's just a work-around. Real fix would be to use different font that works across all browsers. I.e Arial

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
font-family: "Arial Narrow",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

From the H1 and use the default font. Or employ a open source font from Google or Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't recognize the font "Arial Narrow"
So you have 2 options

- Option 1:

At the font so firefox can recognize it:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Arial Narrow";
  src: url(http://linktofont.com);
}
```

- Option 2: use a font that's known by all browsers